# Julia installation via homebrew

Tags: julia, homebrew

I tried, to install **JULIA** via following command `brew cask install julia`.

But in the end I've got the following

`permission denied` errors:

```
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'julia'.
==> Installing Cask julia
==> Purging files for version 1.3.0 of Cask julia
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Caskroom/julia
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:578:in `mkpath'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/unpack_strategy.rb:122:in `extract'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/unpack_strategy.rb:143:in `block in extract_nestedly'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
.
.
.

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/abstract_command.rb:36:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:92:in `run_command'
```

Comment: Have you checked the URL given in the error message?

Comment: It's homebrew repository. Not very relevant.

Comment: It is relevant, because it documents the common issues like yours: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/doc/reporting_bugs/permission_denied_error.md

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. `cd /usr/local/Caskroom/`
2. `sudo chmod g+w .`